# Emacs custom background color by mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use emacs to edit a number of file types, and would like an easy visual queue to tell .c files from .vhd or .py files, for instance.  How can I add a custom background color to the major mode for that language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this via hooks. Among other things you can hook is when a new major mode starts. Put something like this into your .emacs file, and emacs will set your background color to purple every time you go into Python mode.

```
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (set-background-color "purple")))
```

Resetting the background color to the default in the case that you switch back to a mode that doesn't have an explicit set-background hook for it is left as an exercise for the reader.

You can also manually set the background color with M-x set-background-color

Comment: Note that you cannot change the background color *per buffer* or *per window* though, only per frame (see Trey Jackson's answer below).

Answer (score 5):

For posterity, as this thread is 4 years old, it is now possible in Emacs 24.4+ to change faces on a buffer local level. Simply define a face and use `(face-remap-add-relative)` to swap out whatever face you want with it.

Define a `defface`:

```
(defface my-special-face '((t :background "aqua")))
```

Then add a hook to the mode of your choice:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (face-remap-add-relative 'default 'my-special-face)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set the background color on a buffer-by-buffer basis.  See the SU question [How can I change the background colour of a single emacs buffer?](https://superuser.com/questions/153784/how-can-i-change-the-background-colour-of-a-single-emacs-buffer/153820#153820).

The first answer there shows how you can change the background for a single Emacs frame, which might work for you if you have one frame per file (or per mode).