# How to set a theme for specific project (Projectile) in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, projectile

Is there a possibility to set a specific color theme or just to hook on a specific project to run custom elisp?

So the idea is to automatically set a color theme or background-color when I open a file from a specific project (path)? E.g. I can work with multiple projects in different frames and instantly know where I am. May be this can written in .projectile file somehow ?

Here by frame I mean Frame not just a buffer.

Comment: This would be awesome. But projectile probably doesn't have anything for this out of the box.

Comment: Bleakly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3927768/1309352

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this as of now but there is a discussion going on here for something similar in the
[Projectile issue list](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/139). However you can use  a `.dir-locals.el` file to get this done. I am guessing something similar would be implemented for projectile using `.projectile` file in the future once the devs decide upon it.

`dir-locals.el` is intended to set local variables for all files in that particular directory you could checkout the docs or this [blog post](http://joelmccracken.github.io/entries/project-local-variables-in-projectile-with-dirlocals/) for the details. It's not particularly designed to run elisp code (setting a theme is a load-theme function call I believe) for good reason. However you can use eval variable to work around this and emacs will ask you whether to run the code.

```
((nil . ((eval . (load-theme 'molokai 
                         )
           ))))
```

or you could do something even fancier according to the major modes.

```
 ((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t)
          (tab-width . 4)
          (fill-column . 80)))
  ;; Warn about spaces used for indentation:
  (haskell-mode . ((eval . (highlight-regexp "^ *"))))
  (c-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD")))
  (java-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD")))
  ("src/imported"
   . ((nil . ((change-log-default-name . "ChangeLog.local"))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

The latest projectile (projectile-20140716.416) now supports hooking in arbitrary elisp after project switch, elisp such as:

```
  (load-theme 'zenburn t)
```

An example script that exploits the hook is here: http://github.com/jfeltz/projectile-load-settings

Comment: These are great news, will check this out!