# in GNU Emacs, how to set background color by mode?

Tags: emacs

In GNU Emacs, I see that I can set different faces for foreground type in different modes, e.g.:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(message-header-to ((t (:foreground "LightGoldenrod1" :weight bold)))))
```

How can I set the background color for the frame by mode? Such that, for e.g., org-mode background would take whatever the color-theme defines it as, but message-mode background would be black?

Something like this, except that the below doesn't work:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(message-mode-frame ((t (:background "black")))))
```

Comment: To clarify: are you trying to change the background of the *text*, or of the entire frame?  If the former, you can probably just add a `:background` keyword to your first example.  If the latter, as far as I know you would have to set the *frame's* background, which is not the same as setting a window's background.

Comment: Entire frame, i.e. entire background of message-mode.

Comment: Using `buffer-face-mode`, you can make a buffer different than other buffers.  When you set a frame background, it will affect all buffers in the frame.

Comment: Very cool.  Actually, check out the thread to the following question, which looks like it has some answers that would work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516830/custom-background-for-active-window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick example to do it by frame -- i.e. where it will affect every buffer in the frame:

```lisp
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'change-my-background-color)

(add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook 'change-my-background-color)

(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'change-my-background-color)

(defun change-my-background-color ()
  (cond
    ((eq major-mode 'org-mode)
      (set-background-color "honeydew"))
    ((eq major-mode 'text-mode)
      (set-background-color "blue"))
    (t
      (set-background-color "red"))))
```

---

And, here is a change the buffer color example:

```lisp
(defun buffer-background-red ()
(interactive)
  (setq buffer-face-mode-face `(:background "red"))
  (buffer-face-mode 1))
```

---

To do it on a window basis is not presently possible; however, here is a link to changing the modeline color as to the active window.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20936397/2112489

Answer (score -1):

> "Entire frame, i.e. entire background of message-mode"

this phrase make me think author mixed up *[frame and window](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frames.html)* in Emacs. Each frame can contains several windows. While *-mode can refer to [each buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modes.html#Modes), i.e. window.
So if you want to set background color *by mode* for each *buffer* with it (but not for frame) then better use mode hooks [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094638/emacs-custom-background-color-by-mode)