# emacs: How to set background color of shell?

Tags: emacs

I am using a theme that I set using `M-x customize-themes`. I would like to changes things a bit in order to make the shell more distinguishable from my other windows. Can I make it so that when I do `M-x shell` I get a shell whose background is, say, black?

Comment: You might take a look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142699/in-gnu-emacs-how-to-set-background-color-by-mode?rq=1), specifically the part relating to per-buffer coloration.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colur,
of background,`<br>`
(setq term-default-fg-color "#FFFFFF")
(setq term-default-bg-color "#211E1E")

Try if it wrks

Comment: *term-default-bg-color* is a variable defined in `term.el'.
  This variable is obsolete since 24.3;  use the face *term* instead. You can do that by *M-x customize-face* *term*